# Convenient way to retain accounts/settings/icons/logins between installs?

Tags: applications, cyanogenmod, backup, installation, google-account

I like installing the latest CyanogenMod nightly now and then. I do so by putting the zip on the SD card and installing it through ClockworkMod Recovery. But every time I do that, I have to do a lot of manual backup and recovery to get the system back to where I started:

- Email accounts
- Text messages
- Home screen icons and widgets
- Login settings for apps such as DropBox and Remember the Milk.
- Wifi settings

My contacts and installed apps are carried over automatically as soon as I've connected the phone/install to my Google account.

Is there a convenient way to get the above points carried over automatically?

Comment: Have you tried the built in OTA updater? you won't need to wipe anything.

Comment: @Kmelkon No, where can I find it? I like to try new nightlies. Can that be done through the OTA updater?

Comment: What are you using for backup/restore? I never used the built-in CM updater (still running CM7.2 where I use CM). But maybe a partly automated backup/restore might be a welcome answer, too?

Comment: Yes, it's great for trying out nightlies, go to settings->About Phone->CyanogenMod updates..
try it out. if you like it, then install cyan delta from the play store so you can update w/o downloading the whole ROM. happy flashing!

Comment: @Izzy It would!

Comment: As you welcome it, I've added the backup/restore solution I had in mind as an answer. Hope it proves helpful – it did plenty of times for me :)

Answer (score 2):

As a (partly) automated backup/restore process seems a welcome option, I might point you to [Titanium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/titanium-backup-%E2%98%85-root/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup). At least in its payed version (I bought it long ago, so I don't remember the differences to the free version), it offers you automated/scheduled backups as well as restores. You can define "labels" (effectively grouping apps) and operate based on those, e.g. just backing up/restoring apps with a certain label. TiBu let's you diffentiate what you want to backup/restore also in terms of "app, data or both", so you've got a bunch of possibilities.

This app also has the possibility to keep a copy of its configuration on your SDCard. Starting for the first time (e.g. on a fresh ROM), it would check for that copy and use it, so its settings survive even a wipe.

You still might need to take care with "system data", as structures (e.g. in the SQLite databases) might have changed. But TiBu can even take care of that if you enable its "migration mode".

Summing up, while this isn't a nice one-click solution, it still might ease your upgrades. Even across different ROMs or even devices (I used it a lot for things like that, and got my apps & data from my old *HTC Wildfire* via *Motorola Milestone²* to my *LG Optimus 4X* that way).

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing a wipe? Back when I still had CM on my S2 (I am on S4, with stock ROM now), I never had to wipe when updating to a minor update (via zip with CWM recover). I retained my data.

However, if you're updating to a major CM update, a wipe is sometimes necessary (esp if it's a major Android update).

Comment: I always wipe everything with ClockworkMod Recovery and then install the zip. What is considered major? 10.1.3 to 10.2?

Comment: @Andreas Something like CM9 to CM10, or CM10 to CM10.1; can be either nightly or stable. You can always check in XDA forums (or CM forums), and see or ask if a wipe is required. Wipe is usually not necessary with nightlies (but again, you need to check the version if it's a major jump).

Comment: Also, if you got caught by a bug in a nightly, there's a risk it may have corrupted some data, which would need a wipe (or a "clear data", if it's only in one app) to fix.